# Android socket app takes too much time to load

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am able to successfully connect to the server using the socket. the problem is activity takes too much time to load. I am changing the TextView for every line in my network class using handler and runnable. It seems like everythhing is done and then i get the output... I have made network as a thread thinking it will run in background and app will load instantly. Any suggestions what can i do?

Main Activity

```
package com.abhishek.ally2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textview;
    String header;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
        header = "GET /ally.php HTTP/1.0\nHost: easyvote.co.in\n\n";
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread connect = new network("easyvote.co.in", 80, header, textview, handler);
        connect.start();
        ((network) connect).statusShow();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Network Class

```
package com.abhishek.ally2;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class network extends Thread {
    Socket client = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    String host;
    int port;
    String responseLine;
    String data;
    String lastMsg;
    public boolean status;
    Handler handler;
    TextView txt;
    Runnable r;
    int count;
    network(String host, int port, String data, TextView status, Handler handler)
    {
        this.status = false;
        this.txt = status;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.data = data;
        count = 0;
        //while(!status)
        r = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Log.d("Response", responseLine);
                txt.setText("Connecting...");

            }

        };
        this.handler.post(r);

    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    public void statusShow()
    {
        try 
        {
            client = new Socket(host, port);
            os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            if(client != null && os != null && is != null)
            {
                os.writeBytes(data);
                while((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    lastMsg = responseLine;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("Response", responseLine);
                }
                os.close();
                is.close();
                client.close();
                Log.d("Response", lastMsg);
                r = new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        txt.setText(lastMsg);

                    }

                };
                this.handler.post(r);

            }
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method `statusShow()` from the `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity`.

Hence the function is executed on the UI/Main thread. Try calling that method from inside the `Runnable r`. Then it will not block the main thread.

**Edit:** This might work (I haven't tested it)

Although the code below might work, you are doing it wrong. The way you are doing it, you don't even need separate class (Let alone subclass it from `Thread`). You could write the `Runnable r` in `MainActivity` entirely and `post` it there.

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
    header = "GET /ally.php HTTP/1.0\nHost: easyvote.co.in\n\n";
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread connect = new network("easyvote.co.in", 80, header, textview, handler);
    connect.start();
}
```

In network class:

```
network(String host, int port, String data, TextView status, Handler handler)
{
    this.status = false;
    this.txt = status;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.data = data;
    count = 0;
    //while(!status)
    r = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.d("Response", responseLine);
            txt.setText("Connecting...");
            String result = statusShow();
            txt.setText(result);
        }

    };
    this.handler.post(r);

}
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
public void statusShow()
{
    try 
    {
        client = new Socket(host, port);
        os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        if(client != null && os != null && is != null)
        {
            os.writeBytes(data);
            while((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lastMsg = responseLine;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Response", responseLine);
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();
            client.close();
            Log.d("Response", lastMsg);

            return lastMsg;
        }
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

Comment: sorry if it sounds stupid but statusShow() has Runnable r inside it. so how can i call statusShow() from Runnable R

Comment: your code cause much delay in application, and still took long time to get response after write data